# Anything wrong with using direct ASCII fonts on webpages?

Tags: html, web

Take this text as an example:

If you make an HTML file copy and paste the above text directly in your text editor from StackOverflow, it will show up on the webpage with that font. Why isn't this the standard way for using fonts in HTML and instead most people just use font color when they could simply use ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, these specific characters have very specific meanings beyond just the font. See Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) and its [Unicode chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf).

Secondly, presentation and content are separate matters. When the appearance of text has no bearing on the meaning of the text, then the appearance should be controlled by CSS, not the text itself. (Plus, why would you sacrifice all manner of flexibility by hardcoding the appearance in the content itself?)